# How to save a canvas consisting of image into an image object

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas which has a image within. Now I am trying to save the canvas as an Image object which I want to use in another canvas. But every time I get an empty canvas (w/o the image). Here is what i am doing:

**canvas.toDataURL()**

```
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj,200,20,100,150);
};
imageObj.src = "images/yoda.jpg";
var canvasImage = canvas.toDataURL();
```

and **canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData()**

```
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj,200,20,100,150);
};
imageObj.src = "images/yoda.jpg"; 
var imageData = context.getImageData(195,15,110,160);
```

But this doesn't seem to save the Image present in the Canvas. Any help?

See live preview

http://jsfiddle.net/tvnbD/17/

Answer (score 1):

You have to move toDataURL inside The onload function. Right now, toDataURL is getting called before the image is done loading.

Comment: tried that,but its still not working.Added full code in jsfiddle.

Comment: in your fiddle you are still copying the canvas before the image is drawn. When I moved the code to copy the canvas into the onload function I got a security error because the image comes from another domain